# Why did the author use 'concerned about' although 'concerned with' fits the context better?

Tags: usage

***concerned with*** means ***interested in*** or ***relating to*** while ***concerned about*** is synonymous with ***worried about***. Why did the author use ***concerned about*** although ***concerned with(interested in)*** fits the context better?

> To help firms learn the skills of mentoring, I often hold company
> retreats to work on management skills and also to set goals for the
> coming year. One exercise in teamwork I do at a company retreat is to
> put the group in a circle. At one particular retreat, there were eight
> people in the circle, and I slowly handed tennis balls to one person
> to start throwing around the circle. If N equals the number of people
> in the circle, then the maximum number of balls you can have in motion
> is N minus 1. Why? Because it's almost impossible to throw and catch
> at the same time. The purpose of the exercise is to demonstrate the
> importance of an individual's action. People are much more
> ***concerned about*** catching the ball than throwing it. What this demonstrates is that it's equally important to the success of the
> exercise that the person you're throwing to catches the ball as that
> you are able to catch the ball. If you're less ***concerned about***
> how you deliver information than with how you receive it, you'll
> ultimately fail at delegation. You have to be equally adept at both.

[The Business of Design: Balancing Creativity and Profitability](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=YFwPEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=One%20exercise%20in%20teamwork%20I%20do%20at%20a%20company%20retreat%20is%20to%20put%20the%20group%20in%20a%20circle.%20At%20one%20particular%20retreat,%20there%20were%20eight%20people%20in%20the%20circle,%20and%20I%20slowly%20handed%20tennis%20balls%20to%20one%20person%20to%20start%20throwing%20around%20the%20circle.&source=bl&ots=IOcDtqPSmD&sig=ACfU3U2UYAuwIa1m5BMjfG4POCextMIs0A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijrcrTieD2AhXCVt4KHSxRDWQQ6AF6BAgMEAM#v=onepage&q=One%20exercise%20in%20teamwork%20I%20do%20at%20a%20company%20retreat%20is%20to%20put%20the%20group%20in%20a%20circle.%20At%20one%20particular%20retreat%2C%20there%20were%20eight%20people%20in%20the%20circle%2C%20and%20I%20slowly%20handed%20tennis%20balls%20to%20one%20person%20to%20start%20throwing%20around%20the%20circle.&f=false)

Comment: I think "worried about" **is** the intended meaning. What makes you think "interested in" is?

Answer (score 1):

To a BrE speaker " People are much more **concerned about** catching the ball" implies that people are worried about their ability to catch the ball. Do they have sufficient dexterity to do so? Will they let their team down if they fail? Hence they are worried about failure. In this context, being **interested** in catching a ball does not make sense.

The same argument applies to the second use of the phrase. **Concerned** can also mean **care** and the sentence could be rewritten

> If you care less about how you deliver information than how you
> receive it,...